# update web.config custom values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to update some values in the web,config through c# code. Here below I am giving the config file which I have,

```html
<configuration> 
 <applicationSettings>
    <ProjectName.Properties.Settings>
       <setting name="Employees" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value>
          <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <string>000001;PSWD;DId\Emp1;Password</string>           
          </ArrayOfString>
        </value>
      </setting>
    </ProjectName.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here in this, based on the employee(DId\Emp1) I want to update the password through c# code.

Comment: there are plenty of ways you can update the web.config file. are you familiar with `XPATH`? if not do a simple google search on how to update .Config file at runtime..

Comment: its easy for appsettings value. what if the values are like given above "applicationSettings".. .. ..

Comment: can any one help me to do this using xpath.

Comment: do you need anyone to help you do a google search ..?

Answer (score 0):

You can just read file and save back.

```
string password = "pass";
//phycial path of the web config file. 
string str =File.ReadAllText(".\web.config");
str = str.replace("000001;PSWD;DId\Emp1;Password","000001;PSWD;DId\Emp1;"& password);
 File.WriteAllText(".\web.config", str);
```

Comment: app pool will always restart if web.config change. Other way is need to write a utility which responds the required data. Instead of call configurationmanger use that utility.